# Sitecore: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uri

Tags: sitecore, uri, sitecore8

```
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
```

I was editing a placeholder item in a local 
Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 151207) instance when I got this error. Now I can't edit, delete, or reset it (or its parent folders). I also can't read the item in the content editor as the error pops up when I click on the parent folder. I've tried deleting/editing it and it's parent folder from the content editor, through code, and through PowerShell commands but the same error always shows.

I've also tried replacing my configs and bin folders with my backup copies, clearing cache, restarting IIS and the app pool, but nothing has helped.

I'm completely stuck. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:
The full error in the logs is:

```
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Data.ItemUri..ctor(ItemUri uri)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.GetItemUriFromSourceItem()
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.get_SourceUri()
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.get_Source()
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetSourceItem()
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetInheritedValue(Boolean allowStandardValue)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.GetFieldValue.GetInheritedValue.Process(GetFieldValueArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetValue(Boolean allowStandardValue, Boolean allowDefaultValue, Boolean allowFallbackValue, Boolean allowInheritValue, Boolean allowInnerValue)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetLanguageFallbackItem.IsItemFallbackEnabled(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetLanguageFallbackItem.Process(GetItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetChildrenCommand.Execute(Item )
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetChildren(Item item, ChildListOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetChildren(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck, ChildListOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.GetChildren(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Collections.ChildList.Populate(ChildListOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.GetItemClones(Item item, Boolean processChildren)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.GetItemClones(Item item, Boolean processChildren)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.GetItemClones(List`1 items)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.GetCheckCloneLinksMessage(List`1 items)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.CheckCloneLinks(ClientPipelineArgs args)
```

Comment: Congratulations on asking the 14th million question on stack overflow :)

Comment: Is there a more detailed error in the log?

Comment: By placeholder item, you mean on the presentation details? Can you try set the raw values as `checked` and see if you can update the item?

Comment: No, it's an actual placeholder item. It stinks because now every page that used that placeholder is broken as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception you provided occurs because you have nonempty invalid value in the `__Source Item - {19B597D3-2EDD-4AE2-AEFE-4A94C7F10E31}` field in your item. `__Source Item` is responsible for storing the original item URI for the clone items.

I don't know how you achieved that because there is a processor `ValidateCloneSourceModifications` in the `saveItem` pipeline that prevents of saving items with invalid `__Source Item` field.

I was able to reproduce your exception by changing the field value in the DB.

**How to fix:**

1. Find you broken field in the master DB -> SharedFields table. The `FieldId` is *'19B597D3-2EDD-4AE2-AEFE-4A94C7F10E31'*.
2. Fix it. It should be something like `sitecore://master/{AE76A034-9491-4B83-99F5-39F227D6FB59}`, where the ID is the original item id. You could also just set `''` as a value, but it will remove the binding to the original item.
3. Clear cache.

It must help.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I figured I might be able to edit it in the DB, but couldn't find the right table. I was able to edit it and fix the issue.

Comment: How did you know the exact GUID? I am facing similar problem, but it is caused by `Parameter name: value`.

Comment: @gtu do you have the same stack trace?

Comment: Not exactly:
```Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Null ids are not allowed.
Parameter name: value
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName)
at Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(String value)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.InsertRendering.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ID p)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.InsertRendering.InsertRenderingAt(DeviceDefinition device, RenderingDefinition) ...
```

Comment: @gtu I'm afraid you've found the wrong SO question. It is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the DB Browser `/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx` with this tool you can also delete items.

If this DB Browser admin tools fail, then I'm curious what's in the master database, check directly in sql what make this item special is than an option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get the same error in the dbbrowser, but I can go down a level further than in the content editor...This is the master db. It's fine in web db. The only difference I can see is that the master one's "_Source Item" and "_Source" fields have nothing in them while the web one's are specifically "<null>"

Comment: If it does not have null, then it contains either an empty string or whitespaces. With an empty string, you'll not receive an exception, because of internal Sitecore checks, therefore you have white space(s) in the '__Source Item' field and this is an invalid value. See my answer.